# React, two buttons into one component

Tags: reactjs, electron

i have a simple electron notetaking app and trying to move it on React
https://gitlab.com/ditsikts/quicknotes/tree/master
here is my component

```
var bttnSetting = React.createClass({
    handleClick: function () {
        if (document.getElementById("settingsMenu").style.display == "none") {
            document.getElementById("settingsMenu").style.display = "block";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("settingsMenu").style.display = "none";
        }
    },
    render: function () {
      return (
        <div>
            <p><button onClick={this.handleClick}>Settings</button></p>
        </div>
      );
    }
  });
  ReactDOM.render(
    <bttnSetting />,
    document.getElementById('buttons')
  );
```

with one button(settings) works fine, when I add second non of them rendered

```
<body onload="fillTxtArea()" style="-webkit-app-region: drag;">
    <div id="buttons"></div>
    <div id="settingsMenu" style="display:block;">
```

What I do wrong??
On devtools `<div id="buttons"></>` contain this

```
<bttnsetting data-reactroot=""></bttnsetting>
```

Comment: Does it work if you only have the close button?

Comment: @DavidGilbertson I remove Close again and no working... Seems I change something when added close button. I update file with one button

Comment: @DavidGilbertson problem was the "var bttnSetting" need the first letter to be capital "var BttnSetting" and at reactdom.render change to be the same with var